# Inexpensive, Reliable Captive Portal

Tags: linksys, router, captive-portal

I do some wifi hotspot installations, and a new client recently asked me if it would be possible to force users to his website when they first open their browsers.  After some Googling I figured out that this is "captive portal".  It's a free wifi hotspot, so my client doesn't need authentication, just wants users to hit his site first.

So, after much more Googling the cheapest solution I can find is DD-WRT and Wifidog.  All you need (as far as I can tell) is a Linksys WRT54G.  I'm comfortable flashing the firmware and setting it up.  If I can make it work for this client I'm thinking about offering it as an option to future clients.

SO- has anyone ever set up captive portal this way?  Is it reliable and easy to support, remotely and securely?  If I set my customers up this way will I eventually end up with Linksys Bricks all over the place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had my eye on [CoovaChilli](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli) for a while, it's an OpenWRT only fork of [ChilliSpot](http://www.chillispot.info/) which  also runs on regular computers. Coova offers commercial support if you need it.

Comment: Thanks!!! I love the interface and it looks like it has *exactly* what I need!

Answer (score 5):

You should really consider [pfsense](http://www.pfsense.com) which is a embedded distribution that does FW/Router and captive portal. It is extremely simple to use and works great.

Comment: Thanks Antoine- all the hardware I could find preinstalled with pfSense cost over US$500.  What I could really use is a vendor that sells Linksys or some other cheaper units preconfigured with software that supports captive portal.

Comment: Well DD-WRT is definently not preconfigured as far as i know... You have to install it. Installating pfsense is really as easy as putting a CD into a CD drive and htting next :-)

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.nufw.org/ for another versatile open-source solution that might help here.

Answer (score 0):

i provide open-wrt routers with WIFIDOG open for captive portal.
Some of our client have already made their own captive portal router.